# How to make System.out calls without affecting current users input (System.in) in console application?

Tags: java, console-application

I have an Java console application, where I constantly read user input for commands. Some of the commands have to run in a different thread and just print to the output results of their run periodically, once in 10 seconds. How do I do that without affecting a user.

Example:

> **ru**Hello!**n**

Which means while user was typing the 'run' command, a thread made an output to console.
Is there a standard way to omit this?

Comment: Consider writing the output of those other threads to some log file instead of System.out

Comment: sure. create a separate UI

Comment: what would you like to see happening instead?

Comment: @fishinear I would like to see the output of a thread in above the current input line. E.e.:
{code}Hello!
>run{code}

Or at least:
{code}>ru
Hello!
>run{code}

Comment: @Stultuske, not possible - console app, can be executing in a remote terminal.

Comment: @Eran, user needs to see the messages instantly, the app can be executing in a remote terminal.

Comment: @VolodymyrB so? do you think google or ebay run on your personal pc? no matter what type of ui, it can always be linked to a remote server

Comment: This likely has more to do with the console than with Java. Which console are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) to deal with this shared resource among many threads.

I wrote a simple example based on this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-thread-mutex-and-semaphore-example/). Below is the main class that gets input from the console.

```
package multithread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
        ExecutorService execService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            execService.submit(new BackgroundTask(semaphore, i));
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            semaphore.acquire();
            System.out.print("$ ");
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            semaphore.release();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        reader.close();
        execService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

And here is the background task class that prints to the console.

```
package multithread;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class BackgroundTask implements Runnable {

    private Semaphore semaphore;

    private int id;

    public BackgroundTask(Semaphore semaphore, int id) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println("Hello from " + id);
                semaphore.release();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems doable, will check this and come back with results.